# Understanding asp.net Identity Sign in process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm a newbie at asp.net MVC. One of those people that has a general outline of how it works, but is looking to get a deeper level understanding of the nuts and bolts. So right now I'm playing around inside of the default account controller asp.net gives you when you create an asp.net application. It comes packaged with identity configured and everything.

```
  // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]                      //this is getting a post from a form
    [AllowAnonymous]                //allow unauthenicated users to access it
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]      
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

The code above is first checking to see if the model we have gotten from the view is valid. If it isn't valid, it returns an error view. If it is valid we are going to create a parallel task that will sign into the account. My question is this: where is this method checking for the list of usernames and their passwords? And how can I embed a database in here that this application checks, vis a vis the Entity Framework?

Thanks a lot, folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it is not creating a parallel task but it's simply invoking the Asynchonous method implementation of signing. There's a difference between parallel and Asynchronous processing.

The `SinginManager` is a baseclass provides default behvior for the `ApplicationSignInManager` class which you can find in `Identity.Config.cs` file.

The dervied class `ApplicationSignInManager` would get registered with Context which would internally provide a DI(Dependency Injection) functionality to provide the instance of `ApplicationSigninManger` via `SigninManager`.

Have a look at the `Startup` class in `Start.Auth.cs`:

```
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
   // The registering `ApplicationSigninManger` for Framework to use.
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

Now how will these registered instance will be available? If you look at your controller.

```
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

The `ApplicationSigninManger` instance would get injected at run time when the instance of AccountController class would be created via DI container at run time in MVC framework.

It's a separate topic; How DI works you should read it to understand how the dependencies gets injected when creating object of a class.

Comment: Gosh, I'm so lacking in this department. Thanks for all the input. Where can I learn more about this? All the MVC asp.net books don't really talk much about this. I know this is off topic, but is there any books that you can recommend?

Comment: you can find a lot of tutorial if you search `"Basics of IoC and DI"` I do not have name of any specific book. The DependencyInjection is not as `complex` as it sound. you might have done it in your programs without knowing it. The concept basically came from IoC(Inversion of control) which comes from `"D"` of `"SOLID"` principles which means `"Dependency Inversion"`. In simple words `Classes should not be creating objects of Dependencies but Caller should be responsible for supplying them.` So control is inverted to Caller from the actor class. It's amazing stuff, Good luck with learning!!

Comment: here's a [simple article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Identity is an open source project. You can find the full source code [here](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). Have a look - it is not a massive project and very well coded.

Regarding the sign-in process you need to look through `SignInManager` class (http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs) which passes control to `UserManager` (http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs).

`SignInManager` does checking of the user. `UserManager` uses EF to query your database to verify data in the DB to the one provided by a user when signing-in.